# Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refer to an existing file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

i want to use maven-jar-plugin to build diff classifier jars,like :

mvn deploy:deploy -P debug , classifier-demo-0.0.1-debug.jar deployed

mvn deploy:deploy -P test , classifier-demo-0.0.1-test.jar deployed.

but failure:

```
Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refer to an existing file
```

pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<groupId>org.lenic</groupId>
<artifactId>classifier-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>local-repo</id>
        <url>file://D:\repo</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <classifier>test</classifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>debug</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <classifier>debug</classifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>${classifier}</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: i think spring-boot-maven-plugin ignore the <classifier> attribute, and could not found `classifier-demo-0.0.1-debug.jar` ,  it only check `classifier-demo-0.0.1.jar` to repackage.

Comment: i'm not sure , i guess

Answer (score 12):

Goal: Repackage
Repackage tries to repackage original artifact i.e projectName.jar. Which is outcome of default package phase of maven i.e **mvn package** command output.

When Repackage goal executes it tries to find projectName.jar.

When you run mvn spring-boot:package at that time projectName.jar is not there.
that why it gives error **Source must refer to an existing file**

Solution:
run command 
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage

Comment: I noticed that when you say mvn package, it skips the webapps folder altogether. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is reason:

`this.project.getArtifact().getFile()`

spring-boot-maven-plugin\src\main\java\org\springframework\boot\maven\RepackageMojo.java

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    // ......

    File source = this.project.getArtifact().getFile();
    File target = getTargetFile();
    Repackager repackager = new Repackager(source) {
        @Override
        protected String findMainMethod(JarFile source) throws IOException {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                return super.findMainMethod(source);
            }
            finally {
                long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                if (duration > FIND_WARNING_TIMEOUT) {
                    getLog().warn(
                            "Searching for the main-class is taking some time, "
                                    + "consider using the mainClass configuration "
                                    + "parameter");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    // ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you set Spring Boot Maven Plugin, you have included spring-boot:repackage into package. So just "mvn clean package" is enough, we don't need "mvn package spring-boot:repackage".

Comment: What about if you'd like to package it into a jar using a specific Spring profile and still retain a "default" profile for local development?