# Cannot package Spring Boot application properly in a multi module project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Basically, I have a multi module project as follows:

```
parent-project
├── core-app
└── web-app
```

`core-app` and `web-app` are both Spring Boot projects, and their parent is `parent-project` instead of `spring-boot-starter-parent`. So because of it, they both have:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

in their `pom.xml`, as well as:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This setup perfectly runs within IntelliJ, yet, if I `package` the application, I get a very small `.jar` and basically if I try to run it executable, I get several `command not found` errors.

If I run it with `java -cp my.jar com.Main` I get `SpringApplication not found`. So from this, I understand that the `core-app` and `web-app` doesn't have all the dependencies within the jar.

If I build it into a standalone `.jar` with `spring-boot-starter-parent` as its parent; it works.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**Update:**

Now that was what's happening when I `mvn package`. However, when I actually execute `mvn spring-boot:repackage` I am getting:

```
Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refer to an existing file
```

As suggested here [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38279392) seems to solve the issue, yet I doubt that it might not be the standard way. For example:

`mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage` does the trick, however, I cannot `mvn clean && mvn package && mvn spring-boot:repackage`. I would appreciate an explanation on this. Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought - What is the need to have multi-module project when you are already shipping your product as a microservice?

Comment: I need to separate domain objects/POJOs into a module so that they can be used by non-technical people in a totally different application.

Comment: You should be running with `java -jar my.jar` instead of `java -cp my.jar com.Main`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, I know, it was only an effort to make that jar run. Thanks!

Comment: When developing a "multi module" project I basically use `<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath />
 </parent>` into the root pom.xml and I refer there the modules `<modules>
  <module>core-app</module>
  <module>web-app</module>
 </modules>`. Where they have simple `<parent>
  <groupId>com.root.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>yourApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>` refering the root and it works fine for me

Comment: Mine is a little complex project and as suggested in the answer by @chrylis, it gets very very complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maven projects can only have one parent, and your "modules" can't be modules unless `parent-project` is the parent. You can theoretically make `project-parent` extend the Boot parent, but that can get complicated in a hurry.

Instead, simply go ahead and use the Boot dependencies and inclusions selectively. Use the `dependencyManagement` and BOM import in `parent-project`, pull in only the dependencies actually needed for each module (probably including `spring-boot-starter-web` for your fat jar), and add the Maven plugin *for standalone far-jar modules only*:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then you'll get standard-sized (usually a few K) dependency jars and the whole treatment specifically where it's required.

Comment: That is actually exactly what I am doing (I have tried with Boot dependencies both in `dependencyManagement` parent pom and child modules' pom) and still getting the error.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Your snippet does not include the `repackage` goal, which is the part that creates the fat jar at the end.

Comment: It actually does, it somehow wasn't posted. But I am sure that the repackage goal doesn't get called even though the `goal` is there, please see above update. Appreciate your help, thanks!